# Fourier Series and Contour Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So I have this function that is defined as follows:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    \phantom{-}1,&\text{ for }x>0\\
    -1,&\text{ for }x<0\\
    \phantom{-}\frac{1}{2}&\text{ for } x=0,\pm\frac{L}{2}\end{cases}$$
And then I found the Fourier Series that repreesents this function:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k\neq0}\frac{i}{\pi k}\left[1-\cos\pi k\right]e^{\frac{2i\pi kx}{L}}$$
And when I graph it taking $k$ to be super large (I put in like $k=10,000$) it gives me a result that looks like $f(x)$, however I'm supposed to show that somehow that this Fourier Series actually produces this function, and I just have no idea how. When I used Fourier Series to solve a PDE it was pretty straight forward to show that the series solved thee PDE, but I have no idea how to do it for a random function I've been given. Apparently I am supposed to rewrite the series as the contour integral:
$$\frac{i}{\pi}\oint_{c_1+c_2}\frac{\pi}{z\sin{z}}\left[1-\cos z \right]e^{\frac{2i z x}{L}}e^{\pm i z}$$
Where $c_1$ is  a line parallel to the real axis, but displaced by a small
amount  above it, from $+\infty$ down to a value between $0$ and $\pi$, e.g. down to $\frac{\pi}{2}$; the contour
then makes a small counterclockwise half loop around $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and proceeds back to $+\infty$ along a
line parallel to the real axis, but displaced by a small amount $\epsilon$ below it and $c_2$ is the same but going to $-\infty$. But $a)$ I am not sure how to evaluate this contour integral, and $b)$ I fail to see the connection between this contour integral and fourier series and the contour integral.

Comment: You keep changing this question while I write, and while I know Fourier and signals/systems stuff, I don't know complex analysis. First though, you shouldn't even need a cosine in the summation as for integer k, it will only ever be 1 or -1. Then, get it in the form of the definition of the Fourier Series and use the well-defined integral equations to find coefficients (see link below). The saw wave example is nearly what you want. Other things to look at would include the unit step function and unit impulse function, as you can write that function as a sum of those and transforms are online

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/fourier-series/#:~:text=A%20Fourier%20series%20is%20a,infinite%20sums%20of%20monomial%20terms.

Comment: The integrals for finding coefficients comes from orthogonality. Integral of $sin(nx)*cos(mx)$ over the period is zero when $n \neq m$. This is also true for complex exponentials (remember Euler's equation), which is why in most signals focused work they use complex exponentials

Comment: If you want to validate that a random equation works, the easiest way is by construction: Prove that every coefficient in your test equation matches the proper integrals as used in the construction of the fourier series (the definition of it), and then also make sure to check convergence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#:~:text=Pointwise%20convergence,-Superposition%20of%20sinusoidal&text=There%20are%20many%20known%20sufficient,function%20is%20differentiable%20at%20x.&text=If%20f%20is%20continuous%20and,the%20Fourier%20series%20converges%20uniformly.

Comment: @cmitch I had to change the question because I realized I was asking the wrong thing, my bad

Comment: @cmitch I understand how to find the coefficients of the fourier series, what I'm more wondering is how and why does that series relate to that contour integral, and how does one even evaluate contour integral, as it is more complicated than any ive seen.

Comment: Can you correct all the typos in $f(x)=\sum_{k\neq0}^\frac{2}{\pi k}\left[1-\cos\pi k\right]e^{\frac{2i\pi x}{L}}$ ?